Nrf52840 Dongle programming with the NRF52840 DK - Using the SWD
I am new to the NRF Connect and NRF board development. I was trying to run a blinky code on the nrf 52840 dongle using the nrf52840dk. I was referencing the following two docs:
https://docs.nordicsemi.com/bundle/ug_nrf5340_dk/page/UG/dk/ext_programming_support_P20.html
https://docs.nordicsemi.com/bundle/ug_nrf52840_dongle/page/UG/nrf52840_Dongle/hw_swd_if.html
However, when I run the code the led does not blink
I took the following steps:

I made sure to connect the dongle the way the schematic is shown, although instead if Vtg pin being present on P20, there is a SWD Sel pin on my board, so for one test I did not connect that and for the other I connected it to the Vdd as shown in the diagram

I added a build configuration for nrf52840 Dongle on the NRF Connect in the VS Code

I clicked Build and then Flash and no errors were shown, but the led does not blink.

Since it was not showing, I rebuild the code and then ran a debug (without the vtg connection since there is not vtg on my side):


JLinkGDBServerCL: SEGGER J-Link GDB Server V7.94e Command Line Version
JLinkGDBServerCL:
JLinkGDBServerCL: JLinkARM.dll V7.94e (DLL compiled Jan 15 2024 15:18:46)
JLinkGDBServerCL:
JLinkGDBServerCL: -----GDB Server start settings-----
JLinkGDBServerCL: GDBInit file: none
JLinkGDBServerCL: GDB Server Listening port: 50631
JLinkGDBServerCL: SWO raw output listening port: 2332
JLinkGDBServerCL: Terminal I/O port: 2333
JLinkGDBServerCL: Accept remote connection: localhost only
JLinkGDBServerCL: Generate logfile: off
JLinkGDBServerCL: Verify download: off
JLinkGDBServerCL: Init regs on start: off
JLinkGDBServerCL: Silent mode: on
JLinkGDBServerCL: Single run mode: on
JLinkGDBServerCL: Target connection timeout: 0 ms
JLinkGDBServerCL: ------J-Link related settings------
JLinkGDBServerCL: J-Link Host interface: USB
JLinkGDBServerCL: J-Link script: none
JLinkGDBServerCL: J-Link settings file: none
JLinkGDBServerCL: ------Target related settings------
JLinkGDBServerCL: Target device: nRF52840_xxAA
JLinkGDBServerCL: Target device parameters: none
JLinkGDBServerCL: Target interface: SWD
JLinkGDBServerCL: Target interface speed: 12000kHz
JLinkGDBServerCL: Target endian: little
JLinkGDBServerCL:
=thread-group-added,id="i1"
=cmd-param-changed,param="pagination",value="off"
0xfffffffe in ?? ()

Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
0x00000578 in ?? ()

And here is the normal blinky script. I did not change it:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <zephyr/kernel.h>
#include <zephyr/drivers/gpio.h>

/* 1000 msec = 1 sec */
#define SLEEP_TIME_MS   500

/* The devicetree node identifier for the "led0" alias. */
#define LED0_NODE DT_ALIAS(led0)

/*
 * A build error on this line means your board is unsupported.
 * See the sample documentation for information on how to fix this.
 */
static const struct gpio_dt_spec led = GPIO_DT_SPEC_GET(LED0_NODE, gpios);

int main(void)
{
    int ret;
    bool led_state = true;

    if (!gpio_is_ready_dt(&led)) {
        return 0;
    }

    ret = gpio_pin_configure_dt(&led, GPIO_OUTPUT_ACTIVE);
    if (ret < 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    while (1) {
        ret = gpio_pin_toggle_dt(&led);
        if (ret < 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        led_state = !led_state;
        printf("LED state: %s\n", led_state ? "ON" : "OFF");
        k_msleep(SLEEP_TIME_MS);
    }
    return 0;
}

To further debug I found this document: https://docs.zephyrproject.org/2.6.0/boards/arm/nrf52840dongle_nrf52840/doc/index.html#programming-and-debugging
So I changed
fstab-stock to fstab-debugger
BOARD_HAS_NRF5_BOOTLOADER to defualt n

But still the blinking was not happening.
Nrf dongle when I first connected was slowly blinking red, but now it does not blink at all. Nothing blinks
